# How could I rewrite this code snippet so that I'm not manually/explicitly invoking the injector?

Tags: java, guice, anti-patterns

After reading through many code examples for Google Guice, I see a lot of code that looks like this:

```
public class MyModule implements Module {
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
    }
}

public class Widget {
    private Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());

    public void doSomething() {
        Service service = injector.getInstance(Service.class);
        service.run();
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that code which explicitly calls the IoC mechanism (such as `injector.getInstance(Class<T>)` in Guice or `appContext.getBean(String)` in Spring) is indeed an IoC **anti-pattern**.

In these examples I notice there is no mention of the `@Inject` or `@ImplementedBy` annotations, which I *believe* are Guice's workarounds to this anti-pattern.

**How could I rewrite the code snippet above so that I'm not manually/explicitly invoking the injector?** I'd like everything configured so that by the time execution gets to the `doSomething()` method, the application already "knows" what `Service` implementation we'll be using...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make Guice aware of your `Widget` by adding it to a module and injecting it when needed using annotations.

You will need to add `Service` to its constructor:

```
public class Widget {

    private final Service service;

    @Inject
    public Widget(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...interesting. But what if I have, say, 7 dependencies (other than `Service`) inside my `doSomethng()` method? Does that mean I have to create a `Widget` constructor that accepts 7 arguments? Is this really my only option here? And thanks!

Comment: @Adam: 8 dependencies is too many. Some of them are probably used together to do some specific thing(s) and should be grouped into some other object that provides that functionality.

Comment: Thanks @ColinD - good point. What would this "other object" be? A `WidgetDependenciesFactory`, perhaps?

Comment: @AdamTannon, that would just introduce an unnecessary layer of indirection. Ideally, you would examine how you're using those 7 dependencies and try to divide them up based on some logical boundary, then move some of the logic previously performed in the doSomething method into the new object.

Comment: @Adam: No, preferably it would hide the dependencies it encapsulates from the `Widget` entirely and just expose method(s) that make use of those dependencies to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie with Guice, but why not injecting the service to Widget?

```
@Inject
public Widget (Service service) {
    this.service = service;
    ...
}
public void doSomething() {
    service.run();
    ...
}
```

Or, inject a provider that returns a service.

Comment: Thanks Eyal! Please see my comment below @Bringham's response - I have the same question for you!

Comment: just saw your question :) well, 7 dependencies, as it is mentioned in Bringham's is too much. it is a smell that something is having too much responsibilities.